# Multiple Key Press handling in mfc

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

How to handle multiple key press in MFC. I have tried for few key combinations.But How to generalize for all key combination.

```
BOOL Test::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg){
   if(pMsg->message==WM_KEYDOWN ) 
   {    
       if(pMsg->wParam == 'C' || pMsg->wParam == 'V')
       {
           if(GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) < 0){
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: `PreTranslateMessage` is dangerous territory. Whenever your application enters a modal message loop (e.g. during sizing/moving, in a menu, or a modal dialog), `PreTranslateMessage` won't run. While I don't know your ultimate goal, I'll have to guess and suggest looking into [Keyboard Accelerators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645526.aspx).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way is to handle [WM_CUT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649023(v=vs.85).aspx), [WM_COPY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649022%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [WM_PASTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649028(v=vs.85).aspx), because the copy/paste operations could be completed not only Ctrl+C, but CTrl+Insert, and so on ... if you want to handle these things ...

"PreTranslateMessage is dangerous territory": really true ! Take care !

Answer (score 3):

You can [GetKeyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms646301(v=vs.85).aspx) and check what keys are down.

```
if ((::GetKeyState(_T('C')) & 0x8000)!=0 && 
    (::GetKeyState(_T('V')) & 0x8000)!=0)
    // C and V are down...
```

You can do this check whenever a WM_KEYDOWN arrives in your PreTranslateMessage function. Using this for normal keys like accelerating will work. The MFC also does its checks for accelerators in the PreTranslateMessage functions.

You should always use GetKeyState because this function check what keys where down/up when the current message you received from the message queue was processed.